# Find the distribution of X

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Assume that the salary of a randomly chosen individual has the exponential distribution with unknown parameter $λ$. Denote by $X_1, . . . , X_n$ the binary responses about salary being bigger than some threshold $(X_i ∈ {0, 1}, i = 1, . . . , n)$ of the $n$ sampled individuals.

Is it $Bern(1-e^{λy})$?

EDIT: Sorry, Let $Y_1, . . . , Y_n$ be the salaries of the $n$ sampled people.

Comment: please, explain what is $y$!

Comment: Which is the set of $Y_i$? Is it $\mathbb{R}^+$? Moreover, do you mean that $X_i = 1$ if $Y_i > T$ and $X_i = 0$ otherwise, where $T>0$ is a given threshold?

Comment: @the_candyman I guess, the answer is yes to both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X_i = 1$ we have that:

$$P(X_i= 1) = P(Y_i > T) = \int_T^{+\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda y}dy = e^{-\lambda T}.$$

Similarly, for $X_i=0$ we have that:

$$P(X_i= 0) = P(Y_i < T) = \int_0^{T}\lambda e^{-\lambda y}dy = 1 - e^{-\lambda T}.$$

Then, $X_i$ is a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p = e^{-\lambda T}$ ($p$ is the probability that $X_i = 1$).